# Pivoting rows to columns in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot, procedure

I've some query, that returns following data:

```
T_REF   T_CUR_CODE   T_TERM   T_TERM_MAX   T_REST1   T_RATE1   T_REST2   T_RATE2   T_REST3    T_RATE3

1       RUR          181      365          5000      10,8      50000,01  11,1      500000,01  11,2
1       RUR          366      730          5000      11,4      50000,01  11,55     500000,01  11,6
1       USD          181      365          100       5,9       1500,01   6,1       20000,01   6,55
1       EUR          181      365          100       5,7       1500,01   5,9       20000,01   6
1       USD          366      730          100       6,3       1500,01   6,4       20000,01   6,6
1       EUR          366      730          100       6,05      1500,01   6,2       20000,01   6,3
```

So as you can see, this query describes rates for refence. Each rate is dependent on the amount (t_rest) and duration (t_term and t_term_max). I need to group all rates for 1 refence and each currency (3 rows, with 6 rates):

```
T_REF   T_CUR_CODE   T_RATE_1   T_TERM_1   T_TERM_MAX_1   T_REST_1   T_RATE_2   T_TERM_2   T_TERM_MAX_2   T_REST_2   T_RATE_3   T_TERM_3   T_TERM_MAX_3   T_REST_3   T_RATE_4   T_TERM_4   T_TERM_MAX_4   T_REST_4   T_RATE_5   T_TERM_5   T_TERM_MAX_5   T_REST_5   T_RATE_6   T_TERM_6   T_TERM_MAX_6   T_REST_6

1       RUR          10,8       181        365            5000       11,1       181        365            50000,01   11,2       181        365            500000,01  11,4       366        730            5000       11,55      366        730            50000,01   11,6       366        730            500000,01
```

I use it in stored procedure as dynamic query (dbms_sql package) and before generating query i now how much rates has each row (for this sample value is 3) and how much different terms has each currency (here the value is 2)

Comment: Will you always have 6 rates (2 rows for each ref/cur) or could it be any multiplier of 3?

Comment: both factors may be different - so it can be 2,4,6,8 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must mention here that Oracle does not allow dynamic pivots. You can read about it [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2302816).

What I can only suggest is that you can use static pivots through queries though.

I have modified your data just a little bit - I have used the `T_REF` column as serially numbered. Here is my solution:

```
WITH tbl AS (
SELECT 1 T_REF
       , 'RUR' T_CUR_CODE
       , 181 T_TERM
       , 365 T_TERM_MAX
       , 5000 T_REST1
       , '10,8' T_RATE1
       , '50000,01' T_REST2
       , '11,1' T_RATE2
       , '500000,01' T_REST3
       , '11,2' T_RATE3
FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 2, 'RUR', 366, 730, 5000, '11,4', '50000,01', '11,55', '500000,01', '11,6' FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 3, 'EUR', 181, 365, 100, '5,7', '1500,01', '5,9', '20000,01', '6' FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 4, 'EUR', 366, 730, 100, '6,05', '1500,01', '6,2', '20000,01', '6,3' FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 5, 'USD', 181, 365, 100, '5,9', '1500,01', '6,1', '20000,01', '6,55' FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 6, 'USD', 366, 730, 100, '6,3', '1500,01', '6,4', '20000,01', '6,6' FROM dual
)
SELECT t_cur_code
       , COUNT(*) AS cnt
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 2) WHEN 1 THEN T_RATE1 ELSE NULL END) AS t_rate_1
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 2) WHEN 1 THEN T_TERM ELSE NULL END) AS T_TERM_1
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 2) WHEN 1 THEN T_TERM_MAX ELSE NULL END) AS T_TERM_MAX_1
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 2) WHEN 1 THEN T_REST1 ELSE NULL END) AS T_REST_1
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 2) WHEN 1 THEN T_RATE2 ELSE NULL END) AS T_RATE_2
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 2) WHEN 1 THEN T_TERM ELSE NULL END) AS T_TERM_2
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 2) WHEN 1 THEN T_TERM_MAX ELSE NULL END) AS T_TERM_MAX_2
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 2) WHEN 1 THEN T_REST2 ELSE NULL END) AS T_REST_2
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 2) WHEN 1 THEN T_RATE3 ELSE NULL END) AS T_RATE_3
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 2) WHEN 1 THEN T_TERM ELSE NULL END) AS T_TERM_3
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 2) WHEN 1 THEN T_TERM_MAX ELSE NULL END) AS T_TERM_MAX_3
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 2) WHEN 1 THEN T_REST3 ELSE NULL END) AS T_REST_3
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 0) WHEN 1 THEN T_RATE1 ELSE NULL END) AS t_rate_4
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 0) WHEN 1 THEN T_TERM ELSE NULL END) AS T_TERM_4
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 0) WHEN 1 THEN T_TERM_MAX ELSE NULL END) AS T_TERM_MAX_4
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 0) WHEN 1 THEN T_REST1 ELSE NULL END) AS T_REST_4
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 0) WHEN 1 THEN T_RATE2 ELSE NULL END) AS T_RATE_5
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 0) WHEN 1 THEN T_TERM ELSE NULL END) AS T_TERM_5
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 0) WHEN 1 THEN T_TERM_MAX ELSE NULL END) AS T_TERM_MAX_5
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 0) WHEN 1 THEN T_REST2 ELSE NULL END) AS T_REST_5
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 0) WHEN 1 THEN T_RATE3 ELSE NULL END) AS T_RATE_6
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 0) WHEN 1 THEN T_TERM ELSE NULL END) AS T_TERM_6
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 0) WHEN 1 THEN T_TERM_MAX ELSE NULL END) AS T_TERM_MAX_6
       , MAX(CASE MOD(t_ref, 0) WHEN 1 THEN T_REST3 ELSE NULL END) AS T_REST_6
FROM tbl
GROUP BY t_cur_code
;
```

This may look lengthy but it is incredibly simple. I have used `COUNT(*)` in the select list so you can see how many rows or records you have for that `T_CUR_CODE`. If the number is not 2, it's time to change the query for you.

I have used `MAX` function that would select only one value in multiple rows, the rest of the values are ought to be `null`.

I hope this helps.